# How to make sense of the "sensors" output?

Tags: fan, temperature

If I run the command `sensors` on my PC, this is the output I get:

```
hp_vendor-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
CPU FAN:        0 RPM

amdgpu-pci-0300
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:      643.00 mV 
vddnb:       768.00 mV 
edge:         +46.0°C  
PPT:           0.00 W  

BATT-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          13.07 V  
curr1:         0.00 A  

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tctl:         +48.2°C  

nvme-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +32.9°C  (low  =  -0.1°C, high = +83.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +32.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +34.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +48.0°C  (crit = +113.0°C)
temp2:         +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp3:        +35.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp4:        +38.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp5:        +28.0°C  (crit = +55.0°C)
temp6:        +40.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
```

What are the various temperatures mentioned here? Which of these is/are my CPU temperature/s?

Comment: Try installing psensor as it is useful GUI version, does not harm and is easy to remove https://linuxhint.com/install-and-configure-psensor-sensor-monitor/

Comment: @darth_epoxy this doesn't give me any new information. It displays the same data (with the same labels) in a window :(

Comment: Do you know you to get to the Synaptic Package Manager? Go there and search for psensor then install it that way. It's a GUI application and mine displays each of my 4 CPU cores separately with the temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

I can explain what the output means.

```
CPU FAN:        0 RPM
```

shows the CPU fan speed.

```
amdgpu-pci-0300
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:      643.00 mV 
vddnb:       768.00 mV 
edge:         +46.0°C  
PPT:           0.00 W
```

shows `amdgpu` sensors: voltage, temperature and some PPT (I don't know what it is), probably it is power consumption of some sort.

```
 BATT-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          13.07 V  
curr1:         0.00 A
```

shows the battery data: voltage, and current amperage.

```
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tctl:         +48.2°C
```

This should be the CPU temperature.

```
nvme-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +32.9°C  (low  =  -0.1°C, high = +83.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +32.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +34.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
```

These are your NVME disk temperatures.

```
acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +48.0°C  (crit = +113.0°C)
temp2:         +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp3:        +35.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp4:        +38.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp5:        +28.0°C  (crit = +55.0°C)
temp6:        +40.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
```

These are temeratures reported by ACPI. The first one is most likely the CPU one.

Comment: Thank you! What I read about the `tctl` temperature is that [it isn't necessarily a physical temperature](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.12/hwmon/k10temp.html#:~:text=It%20is%20measured%20in%20degrees,platform%20to%20control%20cooling%20systems.). I did need help with regard to the ACPI temperatures. Is there any documentation regarding what these temperatures correspond to?

Comment: Only the vendor knows what are these temperatures. `Tctl` should be the CPU temp.